# Reducing Output Page Size Perfomance Improvement asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to improve the speed of my website and perfomance.

I've tried everything under the book from compression handling , whitespace removal , update panels and enable view state false.. but nothing seem to work.

The output page size is still 764 kb.. which is quite a lot. So can you guys tell me an out of the box or any other way to approach this to decrease the output page size!

Comment: You mean only raw html or full page with images,css and so on?

Comment: if u have already tried everything then obviously  u cant remove information part from page.... last thing could be like in a grid show only 10 rows and request more when required

Comment: @x2 the view source file.. when the page is open and right click on browser to view source... that runs up to 764kb!

Comment: is it a large table or what is as large?

Comment: What is the page about?  What's the composition? text mostly? script? css? image? grid? lots of form elements?

Comment: text mostly.. java scripts and css and image files are a plenty..

Answer (score 3):

1. Put styles to external css files
2. Put javascript to external files
3. Try to use divs instead of tables for positioning
4. Short id names can help too :)

P.S.: it's difficult to advice without seeing the source

Comment: As an extension to short ID names, if you are not referencing elements from either code or javascript they do not need an id name at all. We found this saved us a lot of space on our pages.

Answer (score 1):

If it really cannot get further decreased, consider implementing some dynamic solution. You could first only load a main frame (without 'real frames') content page which afterwards loads more content dynamically. May use AJAX (javascript) controls or a custom solution for it.

Also, such big html code still looks strange. I doubt, the information can be (over)viewed at the same time by the user. She would at least have to scroll through some big tables or so? If you need a more smooth experience for the user, a dynamic solution may also show the content in chunks, dynamically loaded via javascript. Every time she scrolls down and a new part gets visible, that content is loaded from the server on demand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Update Panels, try removing it. Alone Update Panel can load script file(s) which can be > 300 KB.